# How to open file and edit and save using wps from my app using fileuri for oreo devices

Tags: android, android-permissions, file-handling

I am trying to open file using thirdparty apps like `wps` from my app.
once we edited file using third party apps, it is not saving file in original location.

I am setting the file permissions like below.

> fileIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_GRANT_WRITE_URI_PERMISSION|Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION);

Even though file is opening in readonly mode and making a copy while saving after editing instead of saving in the location where we opened file.

below is my code

```
Intent fileIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
    fileIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.N) {
        path = FileProvider.getUriForFile(getActivity(), BuildConfig.APPLICATION_ID + ".provider", attachmentFile);
        List<ResolveInfo> resInfoList = getActivity().getPackageManager().queryIntentActivities(fileIntent, PackageManager.MATCH_DEFAULT_ONLY);
        for (ResolveInfo resolveInfo : resInfoList) {
            String packageName = resolveInfo.activityInfo.packageName;
            getActivity().grantUriPermission(packageName, path, Intent.FLAG_GRANT_WRITE_URI_PERMISSION | Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION);
        }
        fileIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_GRANT_WRITE_URI_PERMISSION|Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION);
    } else {
        path = Uri.fromFile(attachmentFile);
    }

        MimeTypeMap mime = MimeTypeMap.getSingleton();
        String type = mime.getMimeTypeFromExtension(fileupload.getExtension());
        fileIntent.setDataAndType(path, type);

        try {
            activity.startActivity(fileIntent);
        } catch (ActivityNotFoundException e) {
            Toast.makeText(activity, getString(R.string.noexternal_applicationnotavailable), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
```

Comment: Actually I am expecting the file to be saved in the original location where we opened. My bad luck file always opening in read-only mode.

Comment: Actually I am expecting the file to be saved in the original location where we opened. My bad luck file always opening in read-only mode. My requirement is I should open file  using wps or some other third party tool from my app and i should able to edit and save in the same location where i opened. But it is working file for the <Oreo devices.